# Error occurs 'An unresolvable error occurred and your changes could not be saved' in mobile App salesforce'

Tags: salesforce1-app, account, record

I tried to edit account records and saved it, getting an error'An unresolvable error occurred and your changes could not be saved'.

This is happening only in mobile App but not in salesforce website.
still i have no clue why error occurs only in mobile app.

can anybody help me?

**Below are the formula used in Account sync status field.**

IF (OR(ISPICKVAL (Synchronisation_Status__c, 'Sync Failed'),ISPICKVAL (Billing_Address_Sync_Status__c , 'Sync Failed'),
ISPICKVAL (Shipping_Address_Sync_Status__c , 'Sync Failed'),ISPICKVAL (Roles_Sync_Status__c , 'Sync Failed')
), 'Sync Failed', IF (OR (ISPICKVAL (Synchronisation_Status__c, 'Sync In Progress'),
ISPICKVAL (Billing_Address_Sync_Status__c , 'Sync In Progress'),
ISPICKVAL (Shipping_Address_Sync_Status__c , 'Sync In Progress'),
ISPICKVAL (Roles_Sync_Status__c , 'Sync In Progress'),
ISPICKVAL (Synchronisation_Status__c, 'Waiting To Sync'),
ISPICKVAL (Billing_Address_Sync_Status__c , 'Waiting To Sync'),
ISPICKVAL (Shipping_Address_Sync_Status__c , 'Waiting To Sync'),
ISPICKVAL (Roles_Sync_Status__c , 'Waiting To Sync')), 'Sync In Progress', 'Synchronised'))

Comment: What if you add a debug log on the user who's doing the action in mobile? Do you get anything?

Comment: @Kris Goncalves,    This Issue is not resolve yet. No team is working for mobile related issues. i have no idea why account is not saving in mobile app and the same record saves successfully in Salesforce sites.

Our team is planning to raise salesforce support ticket against to this issue.
 we know to set debug log for salesforce sites, but where its working.               
 how to check debug log for mobile app issues????

Comment: Account object, we have a formula field' Account Sync status'. i will share formula. i guess because of formula field, record not saving in mobile app.                                   is there any other way to optimize below formula???

Comment: Not able to share formula , it exceeds length of this comment box,not allowing to add comment.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with this information.